# troves of upvotes on jokes

Tags: discussion, reputation

Does it make sense to grant upvotes on hilarious comments and answers? I have seen hundreds of upvotes on single funny jokes that added nothing to the actual topic or discussion.
Does it not bring a distortion into the reputation system?

Comment: No reputation is gained or lost via votes on comments.

Comment: How do you propose distinguishing jokes in order to disallow voting on them?

Comment: As long as no one is insulting then a joke here and there shouldn't be an issue. Or are your pants too tight? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: How could anyone not comment/upvote this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165177/correctly-including-posix-libraries-in-deeply-nested-source-makefiles

Comment: If I was liberal on upvoting jokes, I would spend all my time on the PHP tag.

Comment: don't take me wrong i love jokes! i was just thinking at the diligent guy putting together his best answer and getting nothing and the funny fella getting full of votes because of his cunning :-)

Comment: [Just because it's a joke doesn't mean it's not a valid answer, too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/525478)

Comment: @MartinJames _[slow clap](http://www.quickmeme.com/img/c7/c7637f69873778e8e9b0aed5f581b9e5d878178cdaa23fe3b06f48c7c9bde17a.jpg)_

Comment: Ambiguous pronoun reference in paragraph one @MartinJames which was enough to send us off of the deep end here. We can imagine a group of Elbonian Code Slaves all duct-taped together.

Comment: Case in point: [Why aren't my balls shrinking/disappearing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20550930/176646) and [Why Are My Balls Disappearing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11066050/176646)

Answer (score 12):

Sometimes people have to have fun. As long as this isn't how the majority, or even close to the majority operates (*and it isn't!*), it's perfectly fine. Give me a high-voted 'funny' comment or answer, and I'll show you a thousand examples of votes on serious things*.

So it isn't really a problem.

<sup>* Offer not valid in practice, I'm too lazy to actually go do that.</sup>

Comment: _-1 for being too serious_

Comment: The majority of answerers are dead serious, but at times I doubt if the majority of question-askers is.

Answer (score 10):

I offer for your perusal:

[Flash CS4 refuses to let go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193953/flash-cs4-refuses-to-let-go)

I'll let you decide for yourself if the *technical content* of that question merits that many upvotes, favorites and cheap reputation gain.  Worth noting: that question also attracted 19 moderator flags, and has 44 deleted comments, mostly of the form *"+1 I lol'd, would vote again."*

Also for your consideration:

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

which finally had to get locked because people kept trying to fix [bobince's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince) legendary answer, thinking it was broken (insert picture of Picard facepalm here).

Is humor good?  Well, I will say this: ***Good humor is good, in small doses.***  Anything more than that, and it distracts from the primary mission.

Note that humor isn't the only thing that can distort the voting system:

[Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand in what way you think Mystical's answer distorts the voting system... it is actually a very good explanation of branch prediction. Ok, 13k upvotes is a *really* insanely huge amount of upvotes, but this is an exemplary answer IMO. Or maybe are you talking about the 2nd most upvoted post that is 2 lines of text and that got almost 1400 upvotes?